# mapbox not displaying polygon

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am a beginner to GIS and PostGIS applications.

I am trying to display the polygon on mapbox map but unable to do so.

Following is the javascript code:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'TOKEN';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [115.813867, -31.932177],
    zoom: 12
});


map.on('load', function () {
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'maine',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data':threeHouses
            },
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': '#088',
            'fill-opacity': 0.8
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otmdfcq4/2/).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues with the JS Fiddle you've shared.

1. You haven't included `mapbox-gl.js` & `mapbox-gl.css` as resources, so they are not being properly referenced.
2. You are not declaring your data variable correctly (it should be `let threeHouses =` or `var threeHouses =`)
3. You're also initializing your map with a completely different lat/lon than those that are included in your polygon data

If you address all three of these, you'll have a better chance of understanding whether or not there's a problem.